# what changes makes using Quotation in HTML

Tags: html, angular

```
 <div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]= false> Submit </button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]= "false"> Submit </button>
</div>
```

Is there any difference using Quotation with or without in disabled property.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120320/syntax.html#syntax-attributes) there shouldn't be any difference in general, as long as the attribute value doesn't contain spaces or certain special characters. It is common when minifying HTML to remove redundant quotes. It's usually good practice to keep the quotes there though, but there's no functional difference in your example above.